# Cannot reference a local function error in Xcode 6 beta 6

Tags: xcode, swift

I have just updated to Xcode 6 beta 6 from beta 4 and I am receiving an error that I don't understand.

I am getting the error 'Cannot reference a local function from another local function'.

```
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Start Over", message: "Are you sure you want to start over? This will erase your budget and all transactions.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I'm sure!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in
        resetView()
        }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The error is on the resetView() line of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message is very explicative.

`resetView` is a local function and you cannot refer to it from another local function.

In order to fix the issue move `resetView` outside of the local scope.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to make `resetView` a local closure variable instead of a local function. That way you don't have to move it out of the scope where it is now.